# How to properly count a query in pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to dynamically load more posts into my system

This is my code...

```
$stmt = "
  SELECT * FROM `acmPosting` 
  WHERE (`sender`='$thisID' AND `postType`='a')
  OR (`recip`='$thisID' AND `sender`='$userID' AND `postType`='a')
  OR (`sender` IN ($friendsArray) AND `recip`='$thisID'  AND `postType`='a')
  ORDER BY `timeSent` DESC LIMIT $startlimit,10";

    if($stmtCount = $conn->query($stmt)){
        if($stmtCount->fetchColumn() > 0){
            $result = acmPosts($conn, $site, $userID, $stmt);
            $jsonArray['a'] = $result;
            $jsonArray['b'] = 'go';             
        }else{
            $jsonArray['a'] = '<div class="thisOutput" style="padding:12px;">There are no more posts</div>';
            $jsonArray['b'] = 'stop';
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine until it gets to the last set of posts *AKA* if the LIMIT is 100,10 but there are 105 posts in the call it won't call any to the fetchColumn().

I hope this question makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

**EDIT**

How can I determine when I have reached the LIMIT and act accordingly

Comment: I'm confused about why you would expect a table with 95 rows to return when you specify 100 as the offset.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski Well I'm not entirely sure how to combat the issue. It is dynamic so i am sending an int and multiplying it by 10 to get the offset then I add 1 to the int. so at the end if the int=10 then the offset=100. Thats what I need to solve

Comment: So your question is how to determine when you have reached the limit, and act accordingly?

Comment: Yes... I wish I could have thought of how to say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is not very precise but maybe this is what you are looking for:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows